# Adding CSS to an AJAX popup alert

Tags: css, ajax, forms

I've just managed to add AJAX to my mailing list subscribe form. It works and displays a default browser pop up to show the message.

I now want to add CSS styling to it that is a fancy bar alert at the top of the page. I've created the CSS style but am stuck with how to get it in the code. I was using + .addClass("toast-top-full-width") and some other methods but everything is breaking my code.

Any help appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">      </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#subForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.getJSON(
        this.action + "?callback=?",
        $(this).serialize(),
        function (data) {
            if (data.Status === 400) {
                alert("Error: " + data.Message);
            } else { // 200
                alert("Success: " + data.Message);
                ;
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please post a working fiddle

Comment: I can't get it to work in there :( posting a URL on my site where you can see it

Comment: Where is the URL?

Comment: Alert boxes are a part of the browser and can not be styled. If you wanted a custom popup, you would need to build it with HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to style your pop-up, you can't use the `alert` function. You have to add the alert box as an Html element in your page. Then you can style it in any way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a plain old javascript alert I guess.

These things cannot be styled.

Please use something like a Bootstrap Modal dialog for this purpose that are created out of plain HTML and CSS and to which you can apply styles.

Example of Bootstrap Dialog:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```